# Resize a view within a UIStackView to fill the remaining screen size at runtime

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I have the following setup on my storyboard:

```
UIScrollView
|- UIStackView
    |- View1
    |- View2
    |- View3
    |- View4
```

Some content inside View1-4 is dynamic, and View2 has a button. If this button is clicked, the ScrollView scrolls to an offset so that View2 is at the top of the visible screen. View2 has a fixed and known height of 100. How can I now resize View3 after the button was clicked and the scrolling was done, so that it fills the remaining part of the screen, working on all devices? Would I need to calculate the screen height and substract View2‘s height? Or is there any lean way with autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a constraint for the height of View3 that is equal to the root view height, with a constant of `-100`. Then you could simply toggle `isActive` on this constraint, and View3 should automatically resize the way you want it.

Comment: Can I set this constraint value in IB? Most likely not because of the screen height right? Would I need to create an outlet for the constraint and set the value in viewDidLoad?

Comment: You can set it in IB if the UIViewController covers the entire screen, by  making it equal to the view of the UIViewController. You can also make it equal to the height of the UIScrollView, if that is more appropriate. It depends on your view hierarchy. And you need an IBOutlet or normal property to toggle `isActive`.